# Android Studio Emulator Screen is "Scratched" and distored

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

So here's the issue:

[image: Distorted and scratched screen]

Regardless of which Android device I choose, my emulator always looks like the screen's been scratched. When I try to run my app, the screen then becomes so distorted and scratched that it's unrecognizable. I have tried, what I think to be, everything including: deleting all android studio files and redownloading the application and wiping data of each emulator. Regardless of what I do, the screen still ends up looking like that.

Here's the details of my emulator:

[image: emulator details]

I'm using a OSX Yosemite 10.10.5.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with Pie in the emulator. I went to the AVD Manager, clicked Edit for the Pie AVD, clicked advanced settings, found the Graphics and changed it to 'Software'. Then it worked!

Comment: I experienced similar issue with Android TV 11 and changing the Graphics to 'Software' did the trick! Regards!

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and finally just solved it
try to install Oreo system image (API 27) and use it to create new AVD insted of API 28

Answer (score 0):

Well that is strange indeed. Does it happen with emulators from all API levels?

Have you [updated your **Android SDK tools** to version 27](https://www.andreszsogon.com/using-android-8-and-9-emulators-without-android-studio/) already? Also, check out the [Android Blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html) with important SDK tools release notes to help you with the emulator setup. Emulator installation is becoming more and more cumbersome in each SDK release and API level, now they even depend on your type of processor... anyway, if you follow the instructions it should eventually work fine.

Comment: I did. I also redownloaded android studio, deleting all related files, twice and it still doesn't work. I'm just assuming it's my computer, and I'm getting a new one soon anyways, so I'll just wait and try that one.