# Why Android 9 emulator created from AVD is showing like this

Tags: android, android-emulator

I created Android 9 emulator from Android Studio AVD.
But when I start it, it always shows like this in the screen:

[image]

any app running on it also get blurred.
why and how could I fix this?

Comment: Is your android 9 image upto date ?

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51344822/android-studio-emulator-screen-is-scratched-and-distored/51461087