# Android Emulator Screen(API 28) is distorted and scratched

Tags: android-emulator

This question has already been asked here [Android Studio Emulator Screen is "Scratched" and distored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51344822/android-studio-emulator-screen-is-scratched-and-distored) but there is no fix suggested there. I do not have enough reputation to add comment or reply to that question, hence asking it here again in the hope of finding solution to my problem. My issue is exactly similar:
[Scratched and Distorted Android Emulator Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4Fm0.png)

I have tried all the emulators(all come distorted and scratched), tried wiping data on them but nothing helps. My emulator's info is :
[Android Emulator Info:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZVJT.png)

I am using Android Studio 3.2.1 and OS is OS X El Capitan (Version 10.11.6)
.
Please help me in fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies that this is a suggestion instead of an answer...

Anyway, I noticed in the question you linked there was a device in use. That is, a setting in the avd's config.ini (located for me at ~/.android/avd/{{emulator name}}.avd/config.ini) for hw.device.hash2, hw.device.name, and hw.device.manufacturer.

Have you tried creating the emulator using avdmanager? For example:
`avdmanager create avd --name myNewEmulator -k "system-images;android-28;google_apis_playstore;x86"`

This will create the emulator without these device settings as long as you don't specify them in the custom hardware profile.

Lastly, you won't be able to start the emulator from Android Studio. Instead use the emulator tool located in your Android sdk folder and run:
`emulator @myNewEmulator`